# How to store my program's output into a file?

Tags: linux, file, unix, stdout

```
    spykoni@spykoni-H81M-S2PV:~/Desktop/C_plus_plus/MIXMAX/mixmax_release_100_beta$ 
    spykoni@spykoni-H81M-S2PV:~/Desktop/C_plus_plus/MIXMAX/mixmax_release_100_beta$ 
    spykoni@spykoni-H81M-S2PV:~/Desktop/C_plus_plus/MIXMAX/mixmax_release_100_beta$ 
    spykoni@spykoni-H81M-S2PV:~/Desktop/C_plus_plus/MIXMAX/mixmax_release_100_beta$ cat screen.log 
    Script started on Δευ 06 Απρ 2015 05:13:12 μμ EEST
    spykoni@spykoni-H81M-S2PV:~/Desktop/C_plus_plus/MIXMAX/mixmax_release_100_beta$ ./testU01 
    Welcome to the MIXMAX random number generator!
    The curent matrix size is 256, with arithmetic  mod 2^61-1
special entry in the matrix is -1
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                     Starting SmallCrush
                     Version: TestU01 1.2.3
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


***********************************************************
    HOST = spykoni-H81M-S2PV, Linux

    float


    smarsa_BirthdaySpacings test:
-----------------------------------------------
       N =  1,  n = 5000000,  r =  0,    d = 1073741824,    t = 2,    p = 1


          Number of cells = d^t = 1152921504606846976
          Lambda = Poisson mean =      27.1051


    ----------------------------------------------------
    Total expected number = N*Lambda      :      27.11
    Total observed number                 :      23
    p-value of test                       :    0.75


    -----------------------------------------------
    CPU time used                    :  00:00:00.97

    Generator state:
```

I have a program in C++ , which I run in Linux , after running program it gives me a lot of information as an output, and I want to save this information in file in order to see all information later, because it's huge. I can save or let's say record all information from a screen in Linux. As I can see there are various ways to do it , but I exactly want to save information only the output of program. In this example I only want to save only since Starting SmallCrush , because my program prints information starting from there. I don't  want   """ /mixmax_release_100_beta$ cat screen.log 
    Script started on Δευ 06 Απρ 2015 05:13:12 μμ EEST """      extra lines like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your program like:

```
$ ./testU01 | tee testU01.out
```

will show your program's output on `stdout` but also store it into file `testU01.out`.

---

Check [`man 1 tee`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much , it has worked, I was trying but with no result. And you just helped me in  a matter of second

Comment: @Narek : Np :) Mind to accept posts that answer your questions.

Comment: Sorry ,  I didn't understand you, as I am new in stackoverflow, can you explain what do you mean ?